# How to setup Json.NET's Converters depending on custom request's header

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I need to use different Json.NET's JSON Converters depends on header.
Some think like this:

```cpp
services
    .AddMvcCore()                
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // If(my_custom_header_value == "use_first_converter")
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new FirstConverter());
        // Else
        //options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new FirstConverter());
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

For converting depending on custom requests' header, it is impossible to setup by `AddJsonOptions`. You could not access the HttpContext during `ConfigureServices` since there is no request during this process.

For a workaround, try register `IHttpContextAccessor` like

```
public class FirstConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public FirstConverter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var header = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then in `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    // If(my_custom_header_value == "use_first_converter")
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new FirstConverter(httpContextAccessor));
    // Else
    //options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new FirstConverter());
});
```

Check wether to convert by `var header = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;`